# Need identification of a vintage sound systems outlet

Tags: identification, vintage, outlet

I have wracked my brain and searched across the web only to come up empty handed, I was hoping someone here can finally lay my frustrations to rest.

Closest I can find was the NEMA 5-15P to IEC 60320 C5, but the female inserts were too far apart and the connector itself wasn't the right shape.

Thanks for reading, I appreciate it

[image: the outlet and brand of the sound system]

Comment: Please provide measurements including pin diameter, pitch, and overall dimensions.

Comment: that's not an `outlet` ... it's AC power input

Comment: I ain't very tech-savy, sorry about the misunderstanding...

Answer (score 3):

It's very possible this is a "PH163" connector. It was a common connector in the 1950's. There are a few variations, however, including some that are non-polarized or ones that don't connect the middle pin to anything.

If you look around vintage electronics forums and swap meets, you will often find the following brands and model numbers which might be useful for your search:

- Belden 17280
- Volex 17280-B1-8
- Switchcraft LAC3GD

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @Vance Now that you know the specification of the cable, chances are that it will be very hard to find one for sale. If you want to power this device and can't find the cable, I suggest that you open it, and make sure that the center pin is for ground, and the left and right pins are for AC mains (live and neutral). If you need help, make another question here with photos. Next step is replacing the connector with a modern one with a modern cable.

Comment: Could it also be possible for it to be a belden 17952?

Comment: @Vance Yes, that also checks out. In addition, "AC-3G" might also be applicable. There's some limited information [here](http://www.kenselectronics.com/lists/pwrcord.htm), but I don't expect these links to last.